# Change image in grid after click

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have an image in my rows of a basket and would like to change it after it has been clicked.

I have tried to change it in several ways but the image stays the same.

This is the definition in the grid :

```
{name:'Basket', index:'Basket', width:7, formatter: basketFormatter, align: 'center', sortable:false, search:false}
```

The formatter :

```
function basketFormatter(cellvalue, options, rowObject){  

  var rowId = options.rowId;  

  var basket = '<img src="/img/basket_off.gif" border="0" onClick="add2Basket(this,' + "'" + rowId + "'" + ')"/></a>'; 

  return basket;
}
```

And part of the function

```
function add2Basket(image, rowId){

  $(image).attr('src', '/img/basket_on.gif');
  $("#list").setCell(rowId, 'Basket', '<img src="basket_on.gif" />');
```

But none of the above lines changes the image.

Comment: You have: '<img src="/img/basket_off.gif" border="0" onClick="add2Basket(this,' + "'" + rowId + "'" + ')"/></a>'  as img is a self closing tag, no need of extra'/' at end. BTW, what is this </a> closing link tag?  Maybe not your problem but you should write it: '<img src="/img/basket_off.gif" border="0" onClick="add2Basket(this,' + "'" + rowId + "'" + ')">'

Comment: The </a> was a leftover of copy/paste, thanks for noticing, removed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you need fix your custom formatter to produce correct formatter HTML fragment without additional `</a>`:

```
<img src="..." />
```

Next, you don't need use `onClick` with *global* defined function `add2Basket`. Instead of that you can use `onCellSelect` callback which will be called on click on *any* element inside of grid body. You can use `iCol` or `e.target.nodeName` to filter only the events which you need. The setting of `src` attribute is enough to change the image.

[The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SimpleLocalGridWithImagesSwap.htm)

[image]

shows small grid with flags, but by clicking of the flag you can change it to the flag of another country. I used the following code

```
onCellSelect: function (rowid, iCol, cellContent, e) {
    if (e.target.nodeName.toLowerCase() === "img") {
        $(e.target).attr("src", swapList[$(e.target).attr("src")]);
    }
}
```

where I defined in `swapList` which flag should be the next.

Comment: Thanks Oleg, this works fine for the onCellSelect of the cell that I want to change, now I want to change the same cell when something has been entered in another cell, using the afterSaveCell function but when I try this code there : $("#list").setCell(rowId, 6, '<img src="/img/basket_on.gif">'); , the image does not change, if I replace the columnnumber then it does work, combining this breaks your solution too !

Comment: @PhDJ: You are welcome! Are you sure that you use correct `rowId` and correct column index (6)? Do you really use cell editing mode? Only in the editing mode the callback [afterSaveCell](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:cell_editing#events) will be called. I think you should describe your new problem more detailed. You should include the JavaScript code which you use.

Comment: It seems when afterSaveCell was called the formatter was called too, so any change I did was undone, I changed the code in the formatter to change the image and now all works well.

Comment: @PhDJ: I wrote you before that you should **describe in details** what you do. I can't follow you if *I don't know what you do and how you do it in your current code*. You can post new question where you include your current code and describe what you need and what is your current problem.

Comment: Sorry about the confusion, I have abandoned the formatter and I am adding the image server side, it was getting too confusing, you have helped me in this issue and if I need more help I will launch a new question with more code and explanation.

Comment: @PhDJ: You are welcome! I'll try to help you if I would see your new question. My problem is just because I could not understand your last comments. You wrote in your question about "changing the image after clicking" on it, but you don't wrote that you used some editing mode instead of that you used `onClick` in the formatter. If you do have *server side data* and need implement saving of the changes on the server it will be really new problem.